# Load incorporated .exe resources

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, embedded-resource

I have incorporated an executable file into my first project of C# but this doesn't work (I used a `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`)

```
Stream stream = this.GetType().Assembly
    .GetManifestResourceStream("Exeincorporated.exe [or without .exe]");
```

Comment: We need some more info. By incorporate, do you mean that you wish to execute another exe on-demand? Also, what exactly doesn't work - does the `Stream` fail? Does the exe simply not execute? What's going on?

Comment: http://i54.tinypic.com/2dl7rih.png and embedded in resources.resx..doesn't start

Answer (score 1):

If your exe is a .NET executable, you can run it directly from a resource stream by loading it into an "Assembly" object at runtime:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/1a88c947-504b-4983-b229-b08bd8a43a2e/

Otherwise you will need to write the exe off to a temporary location (like the current user's folders) and execute it from there:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

Comment: unfortunately I do not understand much, something simpler?

Comment: Honestly, No.  What you are trying to do is not trivial.

Comment: Once you have copied the file (I would go somewhere other than c: root) you will need to run the process by using the class I provided in my second link.